# iOS Application uploading issue

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, keychain

Using Invited iTunes account having uploading issue from 22 June 2017.

Before 22 June All are working perfect, suddenly getting the following message from XCODE - > Windows - >Organizer.

To submit to the iOS App Store you need to add an Apple ID account that is enrolled in the iOS Developer Program for the development team XXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems :

1. I think your account is not enrolled with Apple Developer Program .
2. IF you are enrolled with Apple Developer Program then your account become expired.
3. If you try to submit an app to the App Store after you have built it using your personal team, you may receive one of the following error messages:

> The selected team does not have a program membership that is eligible
>   for this feature.
>
> To submit to the iOS app store, you need to add an Apple id account
>   that is enrolled in the iOS Developer Program for the development team
>   ‘XXXXXXXXXX’

To code sign your app for submission to the App Store you will need to create developer and distribution credentials for signing your app. For directions about how to manage your account, please see "Managing Accounts section of the App Distribution Guide".

**From**

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1915/_index.html

Comment: I am do not enrolled with Apple Developer Program, I am just invited by others. And this phenomenon was woking perfectly but suddenly getting the "To submit to the iOS app store, you need to add an Apple id account that is enrolled in the iOS Developer Program for the development team ‘XXXXXXXXXX’".

Any suggestion.

Comment: try to check that  your still exist as agent in that account,

Comment: Finally,  I am able to upload build on App Store using following steps.

I am login with one of the team credentials via XCODE. After that, i am able to access Use local signing assets.

Technically don't know what is the issue. But currently resolved my problem.

Thank you for review and commenting on my question.

Comment: is this answer helping you ?